# WPF - Raise KeyEvent Trigger in a Unit Test does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, controls, keyevent

I would like raise a key event in a unit test. When a key is pressed, the TextBox should contain the pressed key in it's text property.

Here is a minimal working example using Xunit:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = Field0Name, Type = typeof(TextBox))]
class MyControl : Control
{
    public const string Field0Name = "Field0";
}

public class MyControlTests
{
    private MyControl control;
    public MyControlTests()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sw.Write(@"<ControlTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Name='Field0'/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>");
        sw.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        control = new MyControl() { Template = (ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(ms) };
        control.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Field0Name_PreviewKeyDownEvent_WriteLetter()
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)control.Template.FindName(MyControl.Field0Name, control);
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(control, tb);

        tb.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, new FakePresentationSource(), Environment.TickCount, Key.A)
        {
            RoutedEvent = TextBox.PreviewKeyDownEvent
        });

        Assert.Equal("a", tb.Text);
    }
}

public class FakePresentationSource : PresentationSource
{
    protected override CompositionTarget GetCompositionTargetCore()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override Visual RootVisual { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDisposed { get { return false; } }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxRaiseEventProject">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Field0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Test report:

[image: test report]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? From your code example, it looks like you trying to test if the WPF TextBox control accepts keyboard input.

Comment: @AbeHeidebrecht Maybe to test that the binding is working.

Comment: i registered for PreviewKeyDownEvent on the textbox and filter some inputs. I want to test that the other inputs were not filtered.

Comment: If @AbeHeidebrecht is correct, then you definitely don't want to unit test Microsoft's code :) I think though you are going about what you want to test from a wrong angle? ..posting a diff approach for you.

Answer (score -2):

This reply is not what you hoping for or may have been expecting for your question. Yet I think it stands, and I hope you re-consider your approach to unit testing after reading it.

I think invoking a button click in the Unit Testing is not the best approach to unit test the functionality. This is one of the reason for patterns such as MVVM, MVC, MVP etc. You want to create a testable class separated from UI usage. (my apologies, as I don't mean to make it sound like a lecture).

So in your example, What I would do is to create a command, bind it to the button for the usage, then base my unit test by invoking the command which would trigger some testable component/part..

```
<Button Command="{Binding PushButtonCommand}"..

some class MyClass
{
    public ICommand PushButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
           return _pushButtonCommand ??
                (_pushButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecutePushButton));
        }
     }

    private void ExecutePushButton()
    {
         //lets pretend it sets some property that you need to test;
         NeedBacon = true;   
    }
```

now this is testable. In the unit test after you create your class, trigger the command
 and check the property:

```
Assert.IsFalse(myClassInstance.NeedBacon);
((DelegateCommand)myClassInstance.PushButtonCommand).Execute(null);
Assert.IsTrue(myClassInstance.NeedBacon);
```

Comment: the OPs tries to unit test a custom control. There is no viewmodel behind a control. The control is also no Button control but a fancy Textbox, how should it make use of a command?

Comment: sounds like maybe you guys need to look in to Automation instead of Unit tests. You could use Automation lib in .NET to invoke various control behaviors.

Comment: could you post a small example using Automation to simulate a key pressed?